# Hide button after 5 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a print button which I want to hide after 5 clicks in MVC application.
For now, I am hiding it on click.
How can I modify the following code to hide after 5th click?

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Print" onclick="hidesubmit();"/>

function hidesubmit() {
   $("input[type='submit']").each(function() {
     $(this).hide();
   });
  };
```

@RGS,
Its not working for me. I am using Jquery 1.10.2. The button is enabled all the time even after trying your code. I am trying to hide it but not disable it. So, I modified it to following but still it not firing.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 var count=0; 
 $("input[type='submit']").click(function() { 
count=count+1; 
if(count==5)
{ 
 $(this).hide(); 
}
 });
</script>
```

Update: I believe count is not working in my case when I try to debug. Its always 0.

Comment: Um, count the clicks?

Comment: Please don't use inline JS it's bad practice.

Comment: Do you have multiple "submit" buttons on your page?

Comment: Its just one submit button.

Comment: Are the script tags in the head of your HTML? If they are, you will need to use `$(document).ready()` as in http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Also, is the Scripts folder definitely two folders up from the HTML file? Are you seeing any 404s in your console?

Comment: Yes, its two folders up since its a MVC web application.
I have other events which are working find except for this one.
I kept the script source and scripts at the bottom of the page to keep page load little faster.
Code
Script Source
Script

Answer (score 2):

Your just need to add a var with count of click on button.
Only when you have the 5th click, you can loop on submit button and hide

```
var count = 0;
function hidesubmit() {
   count++;
   if(count >= 5){
      $("input[type='submit']").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
   }
};
```

And you don't need to loop for hide items :

```
$("input[type='submit']").each(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Is the same think like :

```
$("input[type='submit']").hide();
```

Comment: It's just a first version, i add comment and more information after

Comment: Be careful doing that, placeholders are just as likely to be downvoted. More often than not the downvoter just walks away never to return ;)

Comment: Yes thank for the tips, but it's just I write what i think.. And when i read my comment I say "Ho i miss that.. and update my reply"

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
   count=count+1;
   if(count==5){
       $(this).attr("disabled", true);
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).attr("disabled", false);
   }
});
```

Count the no.of clicks by using variable **'count'**.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ny2ME/

Answer (score 0):

What about being able to have an image display, then after every five clicks it would show another image, but only on the five clicks, and after the fifth click it would go back to showing the orig. image?

Comment: Welcome to the site Yhwhdesign. Since this suggestion is starting a discussion/seeking clarification on what the asker needs, this should be a comment on the question rather than an answer on the question. Try to add a code example of this approach working for the asker to try.

Comment: No problem :) It's a good suggestion, just better suited to comments (which you'll get access to with 50 reputation). It can take a while to get used to Q&A with comments format rather than the forum format.